# How to make a soap call in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, soap

I'm new to Angular and hoping someone can guide me through the process of making a soap call. I can call the endpoint with a Request in SoapUI and it returns the correct Response.  Now I'd like to know how to do the same thing in Angular.

The closest one I could find is [Answer #3](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/909123).  But it doesn't provide enough context for a beginner.

Here's what I've got so far:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SoapService } from './soap.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'Test of SOAP calls'
  name = 'SOAP Prototype';
  response: any;
  
  constructor(private soapService: SoapService)
  {
    soapService.getResponse().subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log("returned data: ",res);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

soap.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class SoapService 
{
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getResponse()
  {    
    const myheaders = new HttpHeaders();
    myheaders.set('Content-Type','text/xml');

    const myparams = new HttpParams();
    myparams.set('username', 'me');
    myparams.set('acctId','1585');
    myparams.set('domain','USR');
    myparams.set('active','true');

    const response = this.httpClient.post<any>('url-to-soap-service', {headers: myheaders, params: myparams, responseType: 'text'});
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Nothing is logged to the console in app.component.ts, nor in soap.service.ts.

I'm see this error in the browser console:

> "<soap:Envelope
> xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap:Bodysoap:Faultsoap:ClientError
> reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in
> prolog; expected '<'\n at [row,col {unknown-source}]:
> [1,1]</soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

I don't see how there can be an unexpected char when the HttpClient is generating the soap envelope.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend building a REST proxy if possible, since there are good soap client generators for server side languages. If you're unable to do that, you'll need to build the soap envelope from scratch, use http client's response type of text, and parse the xml response body to json.

Comment: Our company has a soap url I must use.  Nor do I want to convert to/from json.  XML in => XML out.  I've added my current code to the post.

Comment: You could build a simple http post rest endpoint that proxies to your soap url in a language like java or c# with minimal effort. Then call that from angular. Otherwise, you need to build the request entirely from scratch. `HttpParams()` is not the correct tool. You'll need to construct the http post body yourself.